# Javascript inheritance - how to check class type?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have implemented inheritance in javascript like this:
Parent class:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    ...
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

and children classes:
ChildA

```
class ChildA extends Parent {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    ...
  }
}

export default ChildA;
```

and ChildB:

```
class ChildB extends Parent {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    ...
  }
}

export default ChildB;
```

Now I got from server object which is mapped to one of these children base on flag. This flag is not in objects, so is possible how to later in code what of type is my object?

I tried `myObj.constructor.name == 'ChildA'` and `myObj.constructor.name == 'ChildB'` but it always returns false.

Comment: Looks like you can test `myObj.constructor == ChildA`

Comment: `Now I got from server` JSON does not contain inheritance. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @JonasW. we got same inheritance in server with dto objects, so we also pass flag in json to detect which object should be created in js. I got just created object and need differentiate these two objects. Flag is not maped in these objects in js.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to have a `type` property on your classes that tells what kind of class each one is. It makes checking very simple.

A more involved solution would be to use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which has inheritance and typeguards built in.